# I want to compare two numpy arrays and create a third array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, simpleitk

Like the title says, I want to compare two sitk arrays that have 1s and 0s as elements, and create a 3rd array that has 1s for where both arrays have 1 and 0s for any other cases. The arrays are the same size and are 3 dimensional, but is there a more efficient way to do this than iterating through them with nested for-loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=(2,3,4), dtype=np.int)
print(a)

b = np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=(2,3,4), dtype=np.int)
print(b)

c = np.logical_and(a,b).astype(int)
print(c)
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: that's much more elegant than what I was thinking of. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help, please mark the question as answered then.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr_shape = (1,4,3)
a = np.random.randint(low=0,high=2, size=arr_shape)
print(a)
b = np.random.randint(low=0,high=2, size=arr_shape)
print(b)
# the new array. subtract a and b and get the absolute value.
# then invert to get the required array
d = (~abs(b - a).astype(bool)).astype(int)
print(d)
```

output:

```
[[[1 1 0]
  [1 0 0]
  [0 1 1]
  [1 1 0]]]
[[[0 1 0]
  [0 1 0]
  [1 0 0]
  [0 0 1]]]
array([[[0, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have SimpleITK Images, you can use the And function.

```
import SimpleITK as sitk
result = sitk.And(image1, image2)
```

This is a functional version of the AndImageFilter.  You can read the docs for the class here:
https://simpleitk.org/doxygen/latest/html/classitk_1_1simple_1_1AndImageFilter.html